# How can I create command autocompletion for Fabric?

Tags: fabric

I created a fabric file that contain several commands from short to long and complex. I need to have an autocomplete feature so that when user type `fab[tab][tab]` then all available fab commands are shown, just like we have in bash.
i.e.

```
user@someone-ubuntu:~/path/to/fabfile$ fab[tab][tab]
command1 command2 command3 ..and so on
```

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1):

There are instructions you can follow here: http://evans.io/legacy/posts/bash-tab-completion-fabric-ubuntu/

Basically you run a script that calls `fab --shortlist`, the output gets fed into `complete` which is a bash function that you can read more about here: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Programmable-Completion-Builtins.html

Answer (score 0):

I did this for my new fabfile using fabric 2.5 & Python 3:

`~/.config/fabfile`

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env zsh
_fab()
{
  local cur
  COMPREPLY=()
  # Variable to hold the current word
  cur="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"

  # Build a list of the available tasks from: `python3 -m fabric --complete`
  local cmds=$(python3 -m fabric --complete 2>/dev/null)

  # Generate possible matches and store them in the
  # array variable COMPREPLY
  COMPREPLY=($(compgen -W "${cmds}" $cur))
}

# Assign the auto-completion function for our command.
complete -F _fab fab
```

And in my `~/.zshrc`:

```sh
source ~/.config/fabfile
```

*I updated the fabric 1.X version here: [gregorynichola's gist](https://gist.github.com/gregorynicholas/4489161)*